# AWS RDS Aurora Mysql swap CNAME in failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Since a few days ago, I'm testing a RDS Aurora Writer-Reader (like classic mysql Master-Slave).
Specifically in its recovery capacity agains a failover in the writer, among other task, RDS should swap itself the Writer and Reader Role (all good in this step) and swap the endpoint CNAME so that the application can continue normally.

In my case, this final step not happend, and my application still pointing to the same machine (this machine is in failover and then it's degraded to reader).

To test this, I use "Test Failover" button in RDS panel.

The feature of change CNAME endpoint is mentioned in the official docs:
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#45

In the following paragraph:

> Failover is automatically handled by Amazon RDS so that you can resume
>   database operations as quickly as possible without administrative
>   intervention. When failing over, Amazon RDS simply flips the canonical
>   name record (CNAME) for your DB instance to point at the standby,
>   which is in turn promoted to become the new primary. We encourage you
>   to follow best practices and implement database connection retry at
>   the application layer.

Comment: Are you using the **cluster** hostnames?  They include the words `cluster` and `cluster-ro` in the hostname.

Comment: Thank you @Michael - sqlbot, l, that was the problema. To use the aurora HA capacity, I must use the cluster endpoint (Inside cluster menu). When I read the faq I misunderstood the change of name in the instance endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in @Michael - sqlbot, I fix the problem. When you use aurora in HA configuration, you need to use, in your application config, the cluster endpoint, not the instance endpoint, because the name change inside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I have other question about this. So in route53 what type of record we have to create ? CNAME is ok ? and if I have 2 cluster endpoints I have to create one cname per each cluster ? or just one CNAME ?
I try and I saw that it's not possible to create 1 CNAME with 2 cluster endpoint.
Thanks !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/550984)